# refreshing wallpaper automagically in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, desktop, desktop-customization

I'm looking to set my wallpaper to a picture of the earth, and would like to re-download the picture every few hours. How could I, preferably from a terminal command, refresh the background to display the new version of the file?

Comment: maybe this should be put on ubuntu.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Real-Time Earth Wallpaper For Linux](http://www.simplehelp.net/2010/05/31/how-to-set-a-rotating-picture-of-the-earth-as-your-wallpaper-in-ubuntu/) original article reference.
Last I checked this was available over apt-get on Ubuntu.
Update: [**Real-Time Sunlight Wallpaper** Debian package for Ubuntu](http://realtimesunlightwallpaper.weebly.com/download.html).

The article describes sourcing for the wallpaper from [www.die.net/earth](http://www.die.net/earth/).
It gives the basic steps to set up the download and schedule a rotation with [gnome-schedule](http://gnome-schedule.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: the link doesn't quite solve the situation, but it led me to realizing that the background will automatically update when the image changes.

Comment: @Rixius, very-much. I am not working from my Ubuntu and forgot the path. Check my updated links for more details.